# WebGL 2D Canvas Point convert to 3D world point

Tags: javascript, matrix, 3d, webgl

I have a problem with my code or I expect the wrong value. What I want to achieve is to convert 2D points from canvas to 3D world space point.

If I understand correctly, I should always get the same points regardless of the rotation of the camera because I don't want a VIEW SPACE but a WORLD SPACE point. So imagine that I click on facing wall of cube this between X and Z axis, then that what I think I should get constant Y value and it is working correctly until I make some rotation change to my camera. If we will make that camera is looking on that wall but with some angle then we will be got for each click different values for Y-axis which one should be constant because each point on that wall is on the same Y position.

[image]

```
var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = clientX - r.left;
var y = height - (clientY - r.top);

var projectionMatrix = matrix4.perspective(fov , ratio, near, far);
// convert to clip space
var xClipSpace = x / width * 2.0 - 1.0;
var yClipSpace = y / height * -2.0 + 1.0;
var zClipSpace = 1;
// convert back from clip space to world space
var xyzVec3 = vector3.create(xClipSpace ,yClipSpace ,zClipSpace);
var transfrom = matrix4.multiply(projectionMatrix,viewMatrix);
var inverse = matrix4.invert(transform);
var result = vector3.transformMat4(xyzVec3,inverse);
```

What I doing wrong ?

Comment: I'm not checking if the math is perfect, but overall you are calculating a 3D point in your camera surface and it will always move with your camera. You must still cast a ray from that point (using the view direction) and check if it hits with the cube. That hit point is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your diagram but otherwise your code looks fine.

In most WebGL math a frustum goes -Z in the distance. Of course you can rotate that based on the view. But in any case if you pass clip space [x, y, -1] through the inverse of the (projection * view) matrix then you'll get some point of the far plane of the view frustum. As the view rotates that point moves with the frustum.

> If we will make that camera is looking on that wall but with some angle then we will be got for each click different values for Y-axis which one should be constant because each point on that wall is on the same Y position.

No: If you rotate the camera that entire wall will rotate so points on it will rotate.

Here's a diagram looking down on top of the view frustum in world space. The view is rotating. If clipX and clipY are 0 then the point being computed is on the center of the far plane of the frustum (Z = 1 in clip space). You can see that point rotating even though it stays on the plane. Its position in view space would not change but its position in world space changes because the entire view frustum is effectively being rotated.

Of course you'd get a different value for Y if you rotate the camera.

```js
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

const boxTop = [
  [-1,  1, -1],
  [-1,  1,  1],
  [ 1,  1,  1],
  [ 1,  1, -1],
];

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  const fov = 60 * Math.PI / 180;
  const ratio = ctx.canvas.clientWidth / ctx.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 10;
  const far = 40;
  const projectionMatrix = m4.perspective(fov , ratio, near, far);
  const viewMatrix = m4.rotationY(time);
  // convert to clip space
  const xClipSpace = 0;
  const yClipSpace = 0;
  const zClipSpace = 1;
  // convert back from clip space to world space
  const xyzVec3 = v3.create(xClipSpace ,yClipSpace ,zClipSpace);
  const transform = m4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);
  const inverse = m4.inverse(transform);
  const result = m4.transformPoint(inverse, xyzVec3);
  
  // -------------

  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 150.5, 75.5);
  
  // draw origin
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let i = -200; i <= 200; i += 20) { 
    ctx.moveTo(-400, i);
    ctx.lineTo( 400, i);
    ctx.moveTo(i, -400);
    ctx.lineTo(i,  400);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#DDD';
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-400, 0);
  ctx.lineTo( 400, 0);
  ctx.moveTo(0, -400);
  ctx.lineTo(0,  400);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#444';
  ctx.stroke();
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#888';
  ctx.fillText('x', 140, 10);
  ctx.fillText('z', 5, -65);
  
  // draw frustum
  ctx.beginPath();
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    const v0 = m4.transformPoint(inverse, boxTop[i]);
    const v1 = m4.transformPoint(inverse, boxTop[(i + 1) % 4]);
    drawLine(ctx, v0, v1);
  }
  ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
  ctx.stroke();
  
  {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(result[0], result[2], 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillText(`${result[0].toFixed(2)}, ${result[2].toFixed(2)}`, result[0] + 5, result[2] + 3);
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);


function drawLine(ctx, v0, v1) {
  ctx.moveTo(v0[0], v0[2]);
  ctx.lineTo(v1[0], v1[2]);
}

render();
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.js"></script>
```